# Setting ID of current logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a website, where I'm using the asp.net web administration tool.

When a user logs in, they can see a basic gridview with checkboxes which pulls data from a sql database. Nothing fancy.

Now what I want to do, is save the ID of the logged in user aforementioned sql database.

Scenario: a user checks of some records in the gridview, hits a save button, and those records are saved with the users ID.

I know how to select out the records and all that stuff, I just dont know how to get the user id and pass that on as a sql command.

Comment: You can use User.Identity.Name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET authentication, the `Profile` object should have all or most of the attributes associated with the logged-in user. `Profile.UserName` will give you the username. You can also use `User.Identity.Name`.